# How to two way bind Angular Material datepicker to a string property

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using the Angular Material datepicker component, bound with ngModel to a string property which represents a date. Using the MatMomentDateModule, the ngModel value is a Moment object, and not a string object as I would like. How can I use the date picker to select a date, and have the ngModel output a string representation of that date?

Template:

```
<mat-form-field>
 <input matInput placeholder="Target Start Date" name="targetStartDatePicker"
            [matDatepicker]="targetStartDatePicker" [value]="visit.TargetStartDate" required>
 <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="targetStartDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-datepicker #targetStartDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Controller Property:

`public visit: Visit;`

Typescript Model:

```
export class Visit {
    public TargetStartDate: string;
}
```

Comment: Are you binding it to a string only because of how it displays?

Comment: I'm binding it to a string because this is the model I receive from my API, all dates are represented as strings. It would be nice to manipulate that string value directly with the datepicker control, and post the model to update it. Right now I'm only displaying it within the datepicker.

Comment: Got it. Not sure if you may do a direct two way binding using a string. What you may do is bind to `dateChange` event, which will give you the selected date, and when a new date is selected you convert it to the string format you want and assign it to your date property.

Comment: see if [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvezct?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.ts) helps and if you can alter it according to your needs.